# message of error when plotting a 3D pie chart on R

Tags: r, ggplot2, 3d, pie-chart

I currently have trouble plotting a 3D pie chart whereas it had worked well with a very similar dataset.

Here is my dataset :

```
structure(list(type_de_sejour = structure(1:4, levels = c("Ambulatoires", 
"Externes", "Fictifs", "Hospitalisé"), class = "factor"), nb_sejours_2021 = c(20794, 
365, 0, 7866)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is my code :

```
lab <- paste0(round(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021/sum(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021) * 100, 2), 
"%")


pie3D(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021, radius = 0.75,
      height = 0.1,
      theta = 0.7,
      border = "white",
      col = rainbow(length(lab)),
      shade = 0.5,
      labels = lab,
      labelcol = "red",
      labelcex = 0.75,
      explode = 0.2,
      main = "Répartition des séjours 2021 par type")
```

I get the following message of error :

```
"Error in seq.default(start, end, by = angleinc) : 
  (to - from) / by incorrect"
```

Also, I would like to plot a legend to indicate what the colours mean (they take the values of variable type_de_sejour). I have seen several posts here, but I can't seem to manage to do it on this dataset, so I would welcome any help regarding this issue too.
Here is the code I added :

```
legend(0.5, 1.5, c("Ambulatoires","Externes", "Hospitalisé", 
"Séances"), cex = 0.3,
       fill = rainbow(length(lab)))
```

I think the problem is that the legend is too big as regards the plot...

Comment: What’s the difference to this question by another Gerard? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292428/problems-plotting-a-pie-chart-in-r

Comment: not a lot as regards the second part of my question (the first one though is new on this blog), but it didnt receive any precise answer... so i'm trying here with my cousin's account

Answer (score 1):

**Add legend**

You can use the function `legend` like this:

```r
pie1_PGS <- structure(list(type_de_sejour = structure(1:4, levels = c("Ambulatoires", 
                                                                      "Externes", "Fictifs", "Hospitalisé"), class = "factor"), nb_sejours_2021 = c(20794, 
                                                                                                                                                    365, 0, 7866)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

pie1_PGS <- pie1_PGS[!(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021 == 0),]

lab <- paste0(round(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021/sum(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021) * 100, 2), 
              "%")

library(plotrix)
pie3D(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021, 
      radius = 0.75,
      height = 0.1,
      theta = 0.7,
      border = "white",
      col = rainbow(length(lab)),
      shade = 0.5,
      labels = lab,
      labelcol = "red",
      labelcex = 0.75,
      explode = 0.2,
      main = "Répartition des séjours 2021 par type") 

legend(0.1, 0.9, pie1_PGS$type_de_sejour, cex = 0.7, fill = rainbow(length(lab)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You should remove the rows with 0 value because you can't show them in a pie chart. You can use the following code:

```r
pie1_PGS <- structure(list(type_de_sejour = structure(1:4, levels = c("Ambulatoires", 
                                                                      "Externes", "Fictifs", "Hospitalisé"), class = "factor"), nb_sejours_2021 = c(20794, 
                                                                                                                                                    365, 0, 7866)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

pie1_PGS <- pie1_PGS[!(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021 == 0),]

lab <- paste0(round(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021/sum(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021) * 100, 2), 
              "%")

library(plotrix)
pie3D(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021, 
      radius = 0.75,
      height = 0.1,
      theta = 0.7,
      border = "white",
      col = rainbow(length(lab)),
      shade = 0.5,
      labels = lab,
      labelcol = "red",
      labelcex = 0.75,
      explode = 0.2,
      main = "Répartition des séjours 2021 par type")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: it's very good, my only issue is that it erases the legend for the colours of the plot...

Comment: @gerardlambert, check updated answer with `legend` function.

Comment: your answer is perfect, how come the "tick" is gone ? I would like to accept the answer

Comment: @gerardlambert, Check the answer in your next question. You could use "topright" and inset.